# multi level category listings / tree php function

Tags: php, sql, tree

I'm looking for a php function or mysql stored procedure which outputs the following:

```
1: category 1 > category 2 > category 3 > category 4
2: category 1 > category 2 > category 3 > category 4
...
n: category n > category o > category p > category p
```

so basically i want **last level category id** and **text which display all parent categories in hierarchy** as above. I have the following table:
categories(id,title,level,parentid);
level increases with category depth.

I tried much on google but could not find a solution. can you please help me?

thanks
-Navi

Answer (score 0):

You can do somethig like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE level = 1");
$branches = 0;
$tree= array();
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "X->".$rows['title']."<br>";
    $GLOBALS['tree'][$branches][] = $rows['title'];
    getChildren($rows['id'], $branches);
    $branches ++;
}

function getChildren($id, $index){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parentid = $id;";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $index."->".$rows['title']."<br>";
        $GLOBALS['tree'][$index][] = $rows['title'];
        getChildren($rows['id'], $index);
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($tree);
echo "</pre>";
```

You will have all "branches" in the variable $tree, from then just use foreach to get through the branches...

Hope this helps